# ScrollToFixed not stopping when it reaches footer

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollto, vertical-scrolling

I'm using the ScrollToFixed plugin and the documentation for it can be found here: https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed

Basically I have allowed my checkout to stay fixed on the right to allow the user to enter details as they go down the page the basket will follow. However to make things hard once you click on the Submit card details a little sage pay form opens up which is causing a problem as instead of pushing the footer down it's just going right through it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#reviewbasket').scrollToFixed({
marginTop:20


});

});​
```

Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 2):

Look at this http://jsfiddle.net/ZczEt/167/
In your case use this:

```
limit: $('.footer').offset().top - $('#reviewbasket').outerHeight(),
```